# Flutter. How to scan a barcode without UI

Tags: flutter, barcode, barcode-scanner

How can you scan a 2D barcode using a flutter without the camera's UI? I don't need to see the camera preview. I just want to click on the "Scan" button, and the camera started looking for a barcode, but it did not display what the phone's camera sees in UI.

Comment: I feel that it will be a BAD User Experience. As a user I don't know where to place the scanner to scan. Sometimes it may fail.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into using the qr_code_scanner package ([pub link](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner)). Instead of opening in a new view, it uses a custom view for the preview. You can then manipulate the view's dimensions to fit your needs. Note that making it invisible using `Visibility` or by giving its parent size 0 will disable the camera. Giving it (for example) a height of 1 pixel will still work.

Example code (run with version `0.4.0` of the `qr_code_scanner` package)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'QR scanner demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String result = '';
  QRViewController controller;
  bool isVisible = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 200,
              // 1 pixel, as a height 0 disables the view
              height: isVisible ? 100 : 1,
              child: QRView(
                key: GlobalKey(),
                onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'The barcode value was:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$result',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.visibility),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isVisible = !isVisible;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData.code;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I found that one solution is to put the `QRView` inside a stack, s.t. it is hidden under another view

Comment: I can not run example. I get an error: `/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.`

I'm just starting to learn flutter. And it's hard for me to deal with the flow of errors in order to make the example work.

Comment: You could try running `flutter clean` to clear all existing data and then run it again, sometimes that can resolve such issues. Otherwise it seems that your local Kotlin version is an older one: You might be able to update it via your IDE's settings

Comment: As I understand the compiled code on an older version (1.1.15) than mine (1.5.1). I'm pretty sure kotlin is backward compatible. Or am I wrong about the versions?

Comment: I didn't have this issue before, when using version `0.4.0` of `qr_code_scanner`. Looks like you need to update your local installations or try first with an older version of the package. [issue with instructions](https://github.com/juliuscanute/qr_code_scanner/issues/325#issuecomment-852171803)

Comment: I just added some sample code that works out of the box on version `0.4.0` of the package, and should also run after updating the packages as per my previous comment. Let me know if it works!